# asyncData get profile from db

Tags: mongodb, express, vue.js, mongoose, nuxt.js

So i want to fetch from db using asyncdata and axios, Here's the code, The problem is that no request is sent, And i'm wondering if someone can help me catch the error.

```js
async asyncData({ $axios, store }) {
    try {
      let profile = await $axios.$get('/profile', store.state.auth.id)
      
      return { profile }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.message)
    }
  },
```

```js
router.get('/profile', async (req, res) => {
  const { userId } = req.body

  try {
    const profileUser = await User.findById(userId)

    res.send(profileUser)
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
    res.status(400).json(e.message)
  }
})
```

Comment: you're doing a $get.. `req.body` won't be set, nor will it contain `userId`

Comment: I deleted $ but still, Is there another syntax error ?

Comment: any sort of auth should be done in a header and handled by a middleware before it hits the route handler, router.get('/profile', authProtected, function(...` etc which would then populate `req.user`, with id then you can do `await User.findById(req.user.id)`.. for profiles which are not own, then it would be passed as a param i.e `/profile/:id` and then you would use `req.params.id` (you can abstract the function so it can handle both with param or default to own if you don't want to repeat code).

Comment: the `, store.state.auth.id)` just looks wrong, look at the docs on how to set headers and set the Bearer token etc, and if your using session for user. it would be `req.session.user.id`

Answer (score 0):

You may need to modify your route to the following, if you want to pass the id as parameter

```
router.get('/profile/:id', async (req, res) => {
  const { userId } = req.params.id;

  try {
    const profileUser = await User.findById(userId)

    res.send(profileUser)
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
    res.status(400).json(e.message)
  }
})
```

and add profile id as route parameter

```
async asyncData({ $axios, store }) {
    try {
      let profile = await $axios.get('/profile/{profile_id_here}')
      
      return { profile }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.message)
    }
  }
```

Otherwise, if you want to get the id of the authenticated user (may be resolved from a Bearer token), it needs to be set to the `request` object in you authentication middleware.
In your authentication middleware,

```
const user = await _authService.validateFromToken(bearerToken);
 if (user) {
      req.user = user;
  }
```

then you can access authenticated user as,

```
router.get('/profile', async (req, res) => {
  const { userId } = req.user._id;

  try {
    const profileUser = await User.findById(userId)

    res.send(profileUser)
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
    res.status(400).json(e.message)
  }
})
```

Comment: might need to tweak `const { userId } = req.params.id;`

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I have modified the answer with an example. assuming that you meant when getting user id from the request object rather than the route parameter.
Please correct me if my understanding was wrong